# Table from DataTable doesn't load a chart?

Tags: javascript, html

I display a chart but it hasn't data, it's just empty.
Normally it should retrieve data and display.
In aspx page, it works well but with html I have this.

Javascript Call :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });
    });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was a stupid mistake, I loaded my chart before completing my DataTables. 
So my chart was based on an empty DataTables.

I placed this code

> $('table').visualize({ type: 'line' });

after completing my DataTables and it works.